# Passing response from http.post to component.ts in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass the response from http.post call in the typescript service component to the angular2 component so that i can display them in the frontend. Below is my service.ts and component.ts code structure.

```
getSearchProfileResponse(body) {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(this._url, body, options)
      .map((response:Response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        JSON.stringify(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error is "+ error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }

getProfile() {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    this.searchProfileRequest = _.cloneDeep(this.searchKey);
    this.searchProfileService.getSearchProfileResponse(this.searchProfileRequest)
      .subscribe(
        searchProfileResponse => {
          this.searchResult = searchProfileResponse;
          console.log("response in component is "+ searchProfileResponse);  // this is displayed as undefined
          console.log("search result is "+ this.searchResult);
          this.spinnerService.hide();
          this.showProfiles(this.searchResult);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.spinnerService.hide();
          this.showError();
        }
      );
  }
```

My question is I could see the data from the controller being passed in the response in getSearchProfileResponse(body) method. But the response is showing as "undefined" in the getProfile() method's response. Any inputs is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed putting `return` from `.map()` function.

Try below code:

```
getSearchProfileResponse(body) {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(this._url, body, options)
      .map((response:Response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        return JSON.stringify(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error is "+ error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }
```